# Ansible playbook: url returns 404 with apt-key module while working manually (browser or wget)

Tags: ansible, apt, ansible-playbook

Can anyone tell me why does [this old key](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key) work for me with the `apt-key` module of the `ansible-playbook` and [this new key](https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key) doesn't (**404**)?

The initial key worked for a short while (when I was developing these scripts) but when it expired (2019-12-06), apt's update_cache (correctly) started failing and it was [advised](https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/issues/476#issuecomment-562850659) to switch to the new key, which I cannot get to work with the `apt-key` module. It works well without ansible-playbook:

`$ wget -O- https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key | sudo apt-key add -`.

Both addresses seem to behave more or less the same when looking at them in the browser. Headers are a bit different though. As are file extensions.

## Details:

This is relevant part of my script. Some other `apt-key` and `apt-repository` and `apt` uses are working fine.

```sh
- name: "Install purple-facebook: key"
  become: yes
  apt_key:
#    url: https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key
    url: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:jgeboski/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key

- name: "Install purple-facebook: repo"
  become: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo: "deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_18.04/ /"

- name: "Install purple-facebook: package"
  apt:
    pkg: purple-facebook
```

If I use the new key, it will 404. All output from running is with the `-vvvv` flag.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": null, 
            "file": null, 
            "id": null, 
            "key": null, 
            "keyring": null, 
            "keyserver": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "url": "https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key", 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Failed to download key at https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"
}
```

If I use the old key, it will fail at first `update_cache: yes` (which is the default for `apt-repository`).

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_apt_repository_payload_drREvW/ansible_apt_repository_payload.zip/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt_repository.py", line 548, in main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 559, in update
    raise FetchFailedException(e)

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "codename": null,
            "filename": null,
            "install_python_apt": true,
            "mode": null,
            "repo": "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_18.04/ /",
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": true,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "apt cache update failed"
}
```

#### Background:

I am automating personal PC setups for practical reasons as well as to learn more about Ansible and Ansible-playbooks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was using a more complete address.

Initial url I was given:

```
https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key
```

Works:

```
https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:jgeboski/public_key.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may run the playbook with `-vvv` option which will give you more clue on what went wrong, and the other option is to add `validate_certs: no` to the task `name: "Install purple-facebook: key"` which will ignore cert validation.

Comment: Thanks. The pasted output is already from running it with `-vvvv`. `validate_certs: no` for the old expired key or the new key that gets 404?